# Is it correct to say "greatly insufficient"

Tags: word-usage

From my thesis:

"Well-functioning SDI that contain complete, precise and up-to-date spatial data  help make faster and more informed decisions based on facts and evidence. In Africa, such infrastructure is **greatly insufficient**."

In the second sentence, "greatly insufficient" doesn't sound natural to me. What is a better way to emphasize that the infrastructure in Africa is really insufficient?

SDI stands for Spatial Data Infrastructure(s).

Comment: We usually say 'highly insufficient' not 'greatly'. You can also consider using some of the synonyms like 'deficient'.

Comment: Yes highly insufficient sounds good! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across ***vastly, largely, entirely*** *insufficient*, but not so much *greatly insufficient*.

Google books will give you a guideline though:

[image]

Seems like *[entirely insufficient](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/entirely_insufficient/synonyms)* is the most used after all.

Comment: Thank you that's great! Could you please share a link to the website where you got this graph? When I search for "google books" i just get a database of books and don't know how to use it like you did

Comment: [sure](https://books.google.com/ngrams)